# Length of a quotient of $1$-dimensional Noetherian local ring by a regular element

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $(R,m)$ be a $1$-dimensional Noetherian local ring. $x$ is a nonzero divisor of $R$.
How to deduce the following identity
$$l(R/(x))=\sum_{P\text{ a minimal prime ideal}}l(R_P)l(R/((x)+P))\ ?$$
Here $l(-)$ means the length of the ring.

I have tried some exact sequences of rings with finite length, but this didn't work. I have no ideal how to  construct terms of $R_P$.

Comment: Hint: $R$ has a finite filtration $0= N_0\subset N_1\subset \cdots\subset N_m=R$ such that $N_{i+1}/N_i$ is isomorphic to $R/P$ for some minimal prime $P$.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks. I get it now.